# SQL Server 2008 R2: NEWID() - Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a big problem, since today. Before I could insert Guids into this table.

When I call

```
 INSERT INTO table(ID) 
 VALUES (NEWID());
```

I get a conversion error, what's impossible is.

`ID` is `uniqueidentifier`.

I get this error in only one table. Can't see any differences between table settings.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Do you happen to have a new **trigger** on that table? Maybe it's not *your* `INSERT` - but a trigger - that's trying to convert something and fails....

Comment: Hello, sorry forgot to write, there are no trigger.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you have shown here. Please post the full insert statement, table structure and the exact error message you receive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
 INSERT INTO table(ID) 
 select NEWID()
```

Comment: Thank you all, after generating the create script from management studion, we found a strange default for an other id field(we couldn't delete it ). So we dropped table and recreated it, and now it works.

Comment: @user1082070 If this wasn't the correct answer then don't mark it as such.